# Refused to load the font <URL> because it violates the following CSP directive:font-src *.fontawesome.com data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline

Tags: magento2.4.5, csp, content-security-policy

[Report Only] Refused to load the font '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src *.fontawesome.com data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

[Report Only] Refused to load the font 'https://cdn.livechatinc.com/widget/o-fgfgfg.woff2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src *.fontawesome.com data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

Can someone please tell me how to properly resolve this in csp_whitelist.xml?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create this file: etc/csp_whitelist.xml & add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <value id="livechatinc" type="host">*.livechatinc.com</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'unsafe-inline' data:</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="livechatinc" type="host">*.livechatinc.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Please flush the configuration & try to check.